# Android listView duplicate information

Tags: android, android-listview, bluetooth

i create a bluetooth application this is my device code:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> paireddevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

if(paireddevices.size() > 0)
{

    for(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice : paireddevices)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("titre", bluetoothAdapter.getName() + " - Appairé");
        map.put("description", bluetoothAdapter.getAddress());
        listItem.add(map);
    }
}
```

and this is my broadcast code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {


        //chercher des nouveaux devices

        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("titre", device.getName());
                    map.put("description", device.getAddress());
                    listItem.add(map);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

        mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItem, R.layout.affichageitem, new String[] {"titre", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.titre, R.id.description});

        listview.setAdapter(mSchedule);

    }
```

All works, but when i click for get devices i get a multiple information and if i still click more and more i get more duplicate information :(

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=48265220150914173852.jpg

how can i get only one LG G3D855 and Only one Samsung galaxy S5, and One HC-05...

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use this function for adding anything to your listItem:

```
//WARNING I did not try this code, handle it as pseudo-code:
private void addIfNotContains(HashMap<String, String> map){
    boolean contains = false;
    for(HashMap<String, String> m : listItem){
        if(m.get("description").equals(map.get("description"))) contains = true;
    }
    if(!contains) listItem.add(map);
}
```

And use every place instead of `listItem.add(map)` `addIfNotContains(map)`. I think that's will work.

Comment: thanks but i get a error in for(m:listItem)

        for( m : listItem){
            if(m.get("description").equals(map.get("description")))contains = true;
        }

Comment: hi; this is all error: http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=833257Sanstitre.png

Comment: am trying this:     private void addIfNotContains(HashMap<String, String> map){
        boolean contains = false;
        for( ArrayList m : listItem) {
            if (m.get("description").equals(map.get("description"))) {
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        if(!contains) listItem.add(map);
    } but i get a error in m.get("description") get(int)

Comment: yes, m is HasMap<String, String> not ArrayList, let me modify my code

Comment: Pro, thank you very very much, I love you man, really thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering the same case with services what I did I catch back key event and used arrayList.clear(); , so it will flush previous data and override the new one 
Hope this will help you